# How can AWS DMS perform ongoing replication without replication or CDC enabled on source SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, cdc, aws-dms

According to https://docs.aws.amazon.com/dms/latest/userguide/CHAP_Source.SQLServer.html

> If your database isn't configured for MS-REPLICATION or MS-CDC, you can still capture tables that do not have a Primary Key, but only INSERT/DELETE DML events are captured. UPDATE and TRUNCATE TABLE events are ignored.

How is it possible to capture changes without replication or CDC enabled? Does DMS still read from the transaction log? I'm failing to find more information in the AWS documentation as to how this works internally.

I currently have an issue where the transaction log is being filled up and not cleared, eventually the disk space for the database is filled.

So I'm looking at any options to resolve this issue and came across the above which confused me as its contrary to how I thought the ongoing replication was achieved

Comment: @MitchWheat I'm not sure how to go about it, it looks as though DMS is scanning the events but they aren't getting cleared and eventually filling up the disk space.

Comment: In the default mode, DMS opens a transaction and holds it open until the sync is complete.